# Flutter + Firestore error: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The following code throws this error "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'"

```
if (snapshot.hasData == true) {
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return ListTile(
                  title:  Text(document.data()['title']),
                );
            }).toList(),
          );
        }
```

Is it related to null-safety? how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is related to a Flutter update.

In the newest Flutter update, there is no need in adding the `.data()`.

Removing the`.data()` from the code in the description solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try
doc.get('title')

instead of
document.data()['title']